# Spark : Why some executors are having 0 active tasks and some 13 tasks?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to read from s3 and do a count on the data frame. I have a cluster of 76 r3.4xlarge(1 master and 75 slaves). I set :

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled "true" 
maximizeResourceAllocation "true"
```

When I checked the Spark UI, I am just seeing :

Just 25 executors - in that only 7 have active tasks(which varies between 13 and 28) and the rest are having 0 active tasks. My job is not utilizing the full cluster capacity. The data is having 240 partitions and the total tasks in SparkUI is 241.

Can somebody explain why only few executors are working, why  I am seeing just 25 executors not 75 and how can I utilize full cluster capacity ?

Cluster details:
r3.4xLarge
VCPU cores = 32
Memory = 122 GB

Update 1 :
I tried setting :
    spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled "false" 
    maximizeResourceAllocation "false"

and

```
sqlSession.conf.set("spark.executor.cores", 5)

sqlSession.conf.set("spark.executor.instances", 375)

sqlSession.conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "38G")
```

but still I am not seeing 375 executors in the UI.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the details of the cluster. (memory, vCPUs) and the configuration for workers you are using.

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim Updated in the question